# Writing to db does not save associations

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to write several objects into my realm database.

As they are associated with another object (the RealmUser), I add them to its `RealmList<RealmActivity>` via `getActivities().addAll(activities)`.

I tried this with and without first copying the collection to the realm via `copyToRealm(activities)` and here's the problem. This seems to work as long as I do not restart my app (or, weirdly enough, when I go back to another activity). As soon as I do that, the activities are still persisted in the database, but they're not associated with the user anymore. I tried `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user);` and `realm.insertOrUpdate(user);` (as you can see in the code) and it won't persist the associations longer than for this activity.

My guess is, that the associations are kept in memory but never commited to the actual file (?) and as soon as I leave the activity the memory image of my db is deleted, thus losing the associations, whereas my actual data is persisted into the actual file. So, what do I need to do to persist associations?

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance())
{
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction()
    {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm)
        {
            RealmUser user = realm.where(RealmUser.class).equalTo("userId", userId).findFirst();
            List<RealmActivity> tmp = realm.copyToRealm(activities);

            user.getActivities().addAll(tmp);
            user.getVitalData().addAll(realm.copyToRealm(vitalData));
            user.getDailyActivities().addAll(realm.copyToRealm(dailies));

            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user);
            realm.insertOrUpdate(user);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to persist associations. The code you show should save the associations to disk. Is `userId` the primary key? `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` and `insertOrUpdate` should both work here. Do you ever copy a user to db with an empty `activities` when the app starts? That will overwrite the user object with same `userId` by empty lists in the user object.

Comment: Thanks a thousand times and more for this comment. I actually did save the user with an empty activities list, which was not intended at all! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As beeender already pointed out, I was saving an instance of the user with an empty activities list every time I logged in. That was the problem.